# Does the actual number for random_state matter in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have seen different numbers given for the parameter 'random_state'. I have read that this will make the results reproducible. My question is, will the result vary if I give different numbers (like random_state=1, random_state=10 or any other)?

Comment: Yes, the random numbers that are used  by the algorithms can be different for different `random_state`, thus leading to different results.

Answer (score 0):

Your result will change, in the same way that if you roll a die two times you can get different numbers. But your result will not change in the same way that if you roll a die twice, both times you're doing the same operation (rolling a die).

Changing the number used will not change the probabilities of the random operations you perform.

Answer (score 0):

Random State controls the shuffling applied to the data before applying the split. You can assign any int value to random state. The value of random state should be uniform/same throught the model. If you choose value=12345, it should be same throughout the code.
The result may change to a little extent, it will not make no difference to the predictions.